# How to connect wired devices to a TP-Link router that is in Range Extender mode?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, nas

I got a second router and planned to rework my home network as follows:

Main router is in remote place connected to Internet via a wire.
The second router in wireless extender/repeater mode that is connected to main router via Wi-Fi. And to that second router I want to connect my NAS with a wire.

At the moment the NAS does not appear on the network.
Routers are TP-Link Archer A9 (main) and TP-Link EC220-G5.

Edit: The issue resolved itself.

Comment: What models are your router? What settings have you used for the second router?

Comment: Routers are TP-Link Archer A9 (main) and TP-Link AC-1200 (EC220-G5).

Comment: The second router is in Range Extender mode, it connects to the main one, but when I get into its admin panel, it shows 0 Wired Clients.

Comment: The [manual](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/archer-c1200/) doesn't mention the words "Range" and "Extender".

Comment: That's a different one. Model name is EC220-G5, I did not get it at first

Comment: Do you have a link to the manual? TP-Link seems not to know anything about it.

Comment: I don't. They have a page for it, but it's empty https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/ec220-g5/

Comment: There is not enough data about the router. Perhaps you could add to your post screenshots of the related router's configuration screens and the firmware version.

Comment: Thanks, @harrymc, for jumping in. I will get back a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue just mysteriously resolved itself.

I plugged/unplugged the network wires, tried another NAS port, it worked.

Then plugged the patchcord back to the first NAS' port and it appeared in the network.

Weird.

Everything works as I wanted - second router bridges NAS to main router.